# Changing logo image source with Java Script

Tags: javascript, web

I am Trying to change my logo image source with Java script code. I do not want to add any function but when page loads new image source is reflected  on the header of the page.I do not have Id but class name to target change of source image.I am not able to get results nothing happens can you please point me towards right directions.

```
 document.getElementByClassName("logo-img").src= "url";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method you're using `document.getElementByClassName()` should be `document.getElementsByClassName()` (elements instead of element). This returns an array of elements with that classname, so in this case you'll have to access the first element of that array. Then you can change the `.src`

```
document.getElementsByClassName("logo-img")[0].src = "url"
```

[Here's a working pen](https://codepen.io/paulmartin91/pen/NWpExdP?editors=1011)

Comment: I tried but still it is showing old image src !! On console it is running fine but not showing change in html page !!

Comment: I've added a codepen link, could you please add in the HTML .img element to your question so I can take a look.

Answer (score 1):

`document.getElementsByClassName` returns an HTMLCollection of all elements in the document with the specified class name. As this is an array, you have to access the elements by their index. If you only have one element in the document with the specified class you can use `document.getElementsByClassName("logo-img")[0].src= "url";`.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned, `getElementsByClassName` returns a collection, whereas [querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) gets the first matching item, referenced by the selector, classname or id. Also you can set the `src` using [setAttribute()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute)

```
let url = 'new-logo.jpg';
document.querySelector(".logo-img").setAttribute('src', url);
```

Comment: When I tried to make changes through console nothing is happening !!